# Json encode with strips html tags

Tags: php, json

How to strip html tags to a complete row with json_encode

```
<?php
    $return_arr = Array();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  products ";
    $RESULTS=$conn->query($sql);

    if($RESULTS->num_rows > 0) {
        while($rowz = $RESULTS->fetch_assoc()){
             array_push($return_arr, $rowz);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

My output for a certain field is like( "<.p>"lorem ipsum<./p>lorem lorem lorem <./br>.....")

strip_tags require a string not array

Comment: Do you want remove the html tag? If yes then provide the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    '<p>hello</p>'
    );

array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$val) { $val = strip_tags($val); });

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Above code, in array_walk_recursive will simply get all the array values and will strip the html tags.

Comment: in your code you need to do following 

array_walk_recursive($return_arr, function (&$val) { $val = strip_tags($val); });

echo json_encode($return_arr);

Comment: Thank you very much Mit.agile it wokrs

Comment: Can you please explain what does this code do? If may be useful for future visitors.